# Bucle "for" no me detecta el tipo de fichero. Linux Shell

Tags: linux, script, bucle-for

¡Buenas! Mi problema es el siguiente: quiero recorrer con un bucle "for" todos los elementos (ficheros y directorios) del directorio del usuario, poniendo dentro de este mismo bucle una condición con "if", en la que únicamente me muestre con un "echo" los elementos que sean ficheros ("-f"), sin embargo, al ejecutar el script simplemente no me devuelve ningún valor. De algún modo es como si no leyese de qué tipo es cada elemento.

El objetivo es que únicamente me muestre los ficheros del directorio del usuario.

Aquí dejo el código del script:

[image: script]

¡Gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, [nunca hagas](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) `for i in $(ls dir)`. No solo no hace falta, ya que `for i in dir/*` es suficiente, sino además se va a romper si tus ficheros tienen nombres mismo un poco raros. Por ejemplo si tienen espacios.

Eso dicho, tu script debería funcionar, aunque con los problemas mencionados. No veo porque no, al menos que no tengas ningun fichero en tu directorio. En todo caso, aquí tienes la version correcta del mismo:

```
for fichero in ~/*; do
    if [ -f "$fichero" ]; then
        echo "$fichero"
    fi
done
```

Sino, aun mas simple y mas rápido será usar `find` con el `-maxdepth` para no recorrer subdirectorios:

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

La diferencia es que el `find` te va a mostrar los ficheros escondidos, los cuyo nombre empieza con `.`, también. Si no quieres esto, lo puedes evitar con:

```
find ~/foo -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[^.]*'
```

O bien con

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v '^\.'
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Ahora ya me funciona a la perfección. Un saludo ;)